# Error in Firebase Permission - Unable to access bucket through firebase storage

Tags: firebase

I try to upload some file to Firebase. But the console shows me this error:

```
{"code": 400, "message": "Permission denied. Could not access bucket educasys-e422a.appspot.com. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."}
```

My Firebase database (Educasys) rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
         allow read, write;
      }
   }
}
```

[image: FireBase Image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something. FireStore is also database, don't get fooled by the name. It's a new database service by Firebase, it supports more features when compared to Firebase, e.g. More queries allowed, performance enhancement, etc.

You're trying to upload files to Firebase, therefore, don't go to FireStore, go to the `storage` option on the left panel and change the rules there:

[image]

Then change your rules like this:

[image]

Comment: K.Wu after digging SO over an hour I got hint from your comment. Thank you. This rule is the default one and getting error in that however while using public rule I succeed to upload image. I have used https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules link for rule. Hope you will guide me.

Comment: @Rozina This rule means you'd have to be signed in to upload your files to the storage. Did you make sure you're signed in?

Comment: I am logged in using Authentication user created in firebase. Added rule : // Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    } }}
and upload image code like : val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://mlkittest-89498.appspot.com")
val storageRef = storage.reference
val imgRef = storageRef.child("allout.jpg")
val uploadTask = imgRef.putBytes(data)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Check these 3 things**

1. storage rules should allow read write
   [sample rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc1VW.png)
2. In your code while initializing firebase storageBucket value should be like

   firebase.initializeApp({storageBucket: 'your-project-id.appspot.com'});
3. If want to access some other bucket from the project then get the storage instance like below

   var storage = firebase.app().storage("gs://my-custom-bucket");

source : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start